# Disable Grails 4 loading texts

Tags: grails, grails-4

How do I disable these unnecessary loading texts in Grails 4?

They are pictured below:

[image]

Comment: This is output from gradle - Though i'm not sure why you're running the development time "bootRun" in docker. This is expected - see https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/641#issuecomment-293200370

Comment: It's 1 of 4 services I'm developing. I'm using Docker to maintain consistency across hosts.

Comment: Also its not stuck there 83% message, it keeps printing it unnecessarily which is annoying.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-q` and/or `--console=plain` to the gradle call?

Comment: Thats what i'm saying - bootRun is not intended to be used for deployment - create a executable war/jar to run in docker.

Comment: @erichelgeson Yea I usually create WARs when I'm deploying. I'm using bootRun so the files and be recompiled on the fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the output of Grade with those flags:

`-q --console=plain`